# JavaScript, loop all selects?

Tags: javascript, dom

Well im new to javascript but why does this not work, all i want to do is to get a list of all selects on the page.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
alert("there are " + elements.length + " select's");
for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
{
    alert(elements[i].getAttribute('Id'));
}
```

Edit: the error is that it does not find any selects at all, elements.length is allways zero!

Comment: care to explain what error you're getting? That's fine as far as FireBug is concerned...

Comment: Just as a comment, I'm going to suggest one of the major javascript libraries for this sort of thing, because we can't drill that in around here enough. (jQuery/prototype/YUI/Dojo/Moo) - Yes, it's worth the overhead.

Comment: add this script block end of the page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'r saying that elements.length is always returning **0** for you, this could be because:

- You are running the JS code in the beginning of your page, thus the DOM is not fully available yet

Comment: +1 good point, I was thinking about it and then you've posted your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Try using `.id` instead of of `getAttribute('Id')`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the part of getting id attribute doesn't work for you. Probably it's because you typed there "Id" instead of "id".

Comment: it says "there are 0 select's" all the time, and changing to id does not help as it dosent find any that invalid code didnt do any harm yet..

Comment: Well ARE there any selects on the page?
If so - what browser are you testing this on?

Comment: yes there are selects and im testing IE and Opera, but i only need this script for IE any way...

Answer (score 1):

The usual cause for getElementsByTagName returning zero results in a document with matching elements is that it is being run before the elements appear in the document (usually in the  section and not inside a function that is called onload or onDomReady).

Move the  element to just before the  (END of body!) tag, or use an event handler that fires after the HTML has all been processed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as far as I can see is that perhaps the selects on your page don't have Id's (the alerts in the loop show null)

Comment: All have id's as its ASP.net any its a asp.net control :)